# Using Android AdapterView.OnItemClick Listener to redirect to a new blank activity

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter, onclicklistener

Hey so I followed a tutorial and constructed a list view. everything is populated and want to click on one of the items and redirect it to another blank activity. All of the items in the list view are made and populated in my Dashboard Class:

```
    import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Dashboard extends ActionBarActivity {

    private List<DashboardItems> myDash = new ArrayList<DashboardItems>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

        populateDashboardItemList();
        populateDashboardListView();
        dashboardOnclick();

    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_dashboard, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.homescreen:
                homescreenItem();
                return true;
            case R.id.dashboard:
                dashboardItem();
                return true;
            case R.id.about:
                aboutItem();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private void homescreenItem(){
        startActivity(new Intent(Dashboard.this, Home.class));
    }

    private void dashboardItem(){
        startActivity(new Intent(Dashboard.this, Dashboard.class));
    }

    private void aboutItem(){
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("About")
                .setMessage("Welcome to Save Me! An interactive and intuitive way to protect yourself during emergency situations and keep your location privacy. Made for a Dissertation and Developed by Ankhit Sharma")
                .setNeutralButton("OK" , new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                }).show();
    }

    private void populateDashboardItemList() {
        myDash.add(new DashboardItems("Profile" , "Use this to create/edit your profile" , R.drawable.profile));
        myDash.add(new DashboardItems("Location" , "Use this to set/view your true/dummy location" , R.drawable.location));
        myDash.add(new DashboardItems("Emergency Contacts" , "Use this to select/view your emergency contacts" , R.drawable.contacts));
    }

    private void populateDashboardListView() {
        ArrayAdapter<DashboardItems> adapter = new myDashboardAdapter();
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.dashboardListview);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void dashboardOnclick() {
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.dashboardListview);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked, int position, long id) {

                DashboardItems clickedDash = myDash.get(position);
                String message = "You clicked position" + position
                        + "which is" + clickedDash.getItemName();
                Toast.makeText(Dashboard.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private class myDashboardAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DashboardItems>{

        public myDashboardAdapter(){
            super(Dashboard.this, R.layout.dashboarditemslayout, myDash);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
           //This makes sure we have a view to work with
            View itemView = convertView;
            if (itemView == null){
                itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dashboarditemslayout, parent, false);
        }

           //Find DashboardItem to work with

            DashboardItems currentDashboardItems = myDash.get(position);

           //Image Icon
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.dashboardicon);
            imageView.setImageResource(currentDashboardItems.getItemID());

            //Profile
            TextView profView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.dashtextprofile);
            profView.setText(currentDashboardItems.getItemName());

            //Description
            TextView descView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.dashtextprofiledescription);
            descView.setText(currentDashboardItems.getItemDescription());


           return itemView;
    }


    }
}
```

Now in the function OnItemClick I've tried different combinations to get it to reference another class (my UserProfile.java) yet it doesn't work. The current function clicks it and displays the position and respective name of the item along with a message. I was wondering if you could tell me the proper way to start the intent for adapter view as its all fairly new to me?

The UserProfile.java class is a blank activity.

Ps. whats the main difference between OnItemClick vs. OnClick besides the fact that item is for the item and onClick is the whole area?

Comment: every `VIew` responds to click event so an `ImageView` respons to onclick, `Listview` and co can also respond to onclick, and also responds to onitemclick because they contain or are backed by data represented in views which happen to respond to onclick, so how do you call that? `onItemClick` , since basically the data's are perceived as children or items..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void dashboardOnclick() {
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.dashboardListview);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked, int position, long id) {

            DashboardItems clickedDash = myDash.get(position);
            String message = "You clicked position" + position
                    + "which is" + clickedDash.getItemName();
            Toast.makeText(Dashboard.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent;
            // i do not know how your dashitems are declared
            // but the idea here is you have already gotten the clicked item so what you do is compare them
           // with the available item you have in your dasboarditem like this
           if(clickedDash ==DashboardItems.Profile){ // assuming DashboardItems.Profile is your profile for profile item
              intent = new Intent(Dashboard.this,UserProfile.class); // you place your intent here in the onitemclick method, in the if equal profile condition
            }else if(clickedDash==DashboardItems.Location){ // you can continue with the others, also here
            // assuming location item is declared in DashboardItems as location
                intent = new Intent(Dashboard.this, UserLocation.class);
              }else{
                // put the 3rd item
              }
            // so it is triggered when you click an item
            startActivity(intent); // then you start it this way
            // that's all you need to do
        }
    });
}
```

hope this is what you want

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I was looking for a slightly different answer let me explain...I've got 3 items Profile, Location, and Contacts...Each of them has there own black activity page which I want them to connect to. So when I click Profile it takes me to my UserProfile.Java class, Location to my UserLocation.Java class, and so on. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Hey bro thanks! Just changed the bit to reflect my code regarding the dash items being generated and it worked! Cheers - @Elltz

Comment: glad you found your way, Sir, happy coding.. :) @AnkhitSharma